# ajax returned undefined, console in firebug response only one line of data

Tags: php, ajax

hey guys im trying to get the values of my ajax via json_encode and use $.each to iterate on each result but each input returns undefined value from my php here is the ajax

```
var counter_sub = 0 ;
var html;
          $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'add_subject.php',
               dataType:'json',
                   data:{'func_numbr':'2'},
                success:function (data){
                   $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                    html = "<tr>";
                    html += "<td><lable>Subject: </label><input type='text' name='subject["+counter_sub+"]' value='"+data[i].subj_name+"'></td>";
                    html += "<td><input type='button' id='activate' name='active' class='button' value='Active'> ";
                    html += "<input type='button' id='inactivate' name='active' class='button' value='Inactive'></td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
           $('#curr-elem-tble').append(html);

           counter_sub = counter_sub +1;
          });
                }     
         });
```

and the php

```
<?php
include_once('DBconnect.php'); 
$func_num = $_POST['func_numbr'];

switch ($func_num) {
case 1:
    insert_new_subject();
    break;
case 2:     
    get_elementary_subjects();  
    break;
 }

function insert_new_subject(){
 $level = $_POST['year_level'];
 $subjct_name =$_POST['subjct_name'];
 $units_nmber = $_POST['subjct_units'];

 $insert_subject = "INSERT INTO subjects (subject_name,level,status,subject_units)     VALUES('$subjct_name','$level','1','$units_nmber')";

                if(@!mysql_query($insert_subject)){
                    die('error insert'.mysql_error());

                    }
                    else{
                        $return ['error'] = false;
                    }

echo json_encode($return);                  
}

  function get_elementary_subjects(){

$select_subjects_elem = "SELECT subject_name,subject_id,status FROM subjects WHERE   level='elementary' "; 

    $connect = mysql_query($select_subjects_elem) or die(mysql_error());
    $data[]=array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($connect)){
        $data= array(
            'subj_name' =>$row['subject_name'], 
            'subj_id'=>$row['subject_id'],
            'subj_status'=>$row['status'],
            );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

i chopped each td into different lines of html and concat it with += still cant figure out why does it return undefined. i checked it with firebug the console return only 1 line of data though it iterates through all the results.

Comment: and also, what point of implementing `each` method with `i` and `item` if you use `data[i]`? you can just use `item`

Comment: I begin to understand why prepared statements managed to get a de-facto standard to escape values.. Please escape your user input before you write to MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You're only getting one line because in your while loop, you overwrite the entire array instead of appending to it. Change the array declaration to:

```
    $data = array();
```

and the code in the loop:

```
    $data[] = array(
        'subj_name' =>$row['subject_name'], 
        'subj_id'=>$row['subject_id'],
        'subj_status'=>$row['status'],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
function get_elementary_subjects(){

    $select_subjects_elem = "SELECT subject_name,subject_id,status FROM subjects WHERE   level='elementary' "; 

    $connect = mysql_query($select_subjects_elem) or die(mysql_error());

    $data = array(); //<---changed $data[] to $data

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($connect)){

        //change $data to $data[] 
        $data[] = array(
            'subj_name' =>$row['subject_name'], 
            'subj_id'=>$row['subject_id'],
            'subj_status'=>$row['status']  //<---removed comma here

        );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit; //<---Added exit here
}
```

See my comment in the above code